# After using preventDefault, how do I "re-allow" the submit button to load a page once data has been sent to the database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Perhaps I'm going about this completely wrong, but my goal is to use jQuery, AJAX and PHP together to validate my register form. I currently have it set up so that:

1. The user enters data into the form
2. If any of the data is incorrect an error message is displayed below the form using AJAX
3. If the form is properly submitted the data is sent to the database

Almost everything seems to work, but the problem is that if the form is filled out correctly and I call

```
header("Location: ../index.php”);
```

then it loads my index page on top of the register page, as preventDefault does not allow the submit button to bring the user to a new page. It's like I have two web pages in one browser window on top of one another. Is there a way for me to "re-allow" the submit button to function as normal if the form is filled out properly?

HTML:

```
<?php 
    include "shared/_header.php"; 
    include "shared/_navBar.php";
?>
<div class="wrapper-register">
    <div id="register-account">
        <div class="register-title">
            <h2>REGISTER ACCOUNT</h2>
        </div>
    <form action="shared/_registerAccount.php" method="post">
        <div class="register-input">
            <input id="register-username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="16" placeholder="Username" />
        </div>
        <div class="register-input">
            <input id="register-email" type="text" name="email" maxlength="128" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
        <div class="register-input">
            <input id="register-password" type="password" name="password" maxlength="128" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <div class="register-input">
            <input id="register-confirm-password" type="password" name="confirmPassword" maxlength="128" placeholder="Confirm Password" /> 
        </div> 
        <input id="register-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SIGN UP" class="register-button" /> 
    </form>
    <p class="form-message"></p>
</div>
</div>
    <?php include "shared/_footer.php" ?>
    <script src="javascript/register.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-3.3.1.min.js" />

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form").submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var username = $("#register-username").val();
        var email = $("#register-email").val();
        var password = $("#register-password").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#register-confirm-password").val();
        var submit = $("#register-submit").val();

        $(".form-message").load("../shared/_registerAccount.php", {

            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
            submit: submit

          });
     });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include_once "_databaseHandler.php";

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
    $confirmPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, 
        $_POST['confirmPassword']);

    $errorEmpty = false;

    //Check for empty fields
    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || 
           empty($confirmPassword))
    {
        echo "<span class='form-error'>Please fill in all fields</span>";
        $errorEmpty = true;
    }

    else
    {
        $sqlUsername = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE userName = '$username'";
        $resultUsername = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlUsername);
        $resultCheckUsername = mysqli_num_rows($resultUsername);

        $sqlEmail = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE userEmail = '$email'";
        $resultEmail = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlEmail);
        $resultCheckEmail = mysqli_num_rows($resultEmail);

        //Check if username is taken
        if ($resultCheckUsername > 0)
        {
            echo "<span class='form-error'>This username is already 
                taken</span>";
            $errorEmpty = true;
        }

        //Check if username has invalid characters
        else if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]$/", $username))
        {
            echo "<span class='form-error'>This username contains invalid 
                characters</span>";
            $errorEmpty = true;
        }

        //Check if email is valid
        else if ($resultCheckEmail > 0)
        {
            echo "<span class='form-error'>This email is already in 
                use</span>";
            $errorEmpty = true;
        }

        //Check if email is already in use
        else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            echo "<span class='form-error'>Please enter a valid email 
                address</span>";
            $errorEmpty = true;
        }

        //Check if passwords match
        else if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirmPassword'])
        {
            echo "<span class='form-error'>Passwords do not match</span>";
            $errorEmpty = true;
        }

        //Insert the user into the database
        else
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO userinfo (userName, userEmail, userPassword) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?);";

            $statement = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);

            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($statement, $sql))
            {
                echo "<span>Database error</span>";

                header("Location: ../index.php");
                exit();
            }

            else
            {
                $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $username, $email, 
                    $hashedPassword);

                mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

                header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}

else
{
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    exit();
}

?>

<script>

    $("#username, #email, #password, #confirmPassword").removeClass(".input- 
        error").removeClass(".input-error");

    var errorEmpty = "<?php echo $errorEmpty; ?>";

    if (errorEmpty)
    {
        $("#username, #email, #password, #confirmPassword").addClass(".input- 
            error");
    }

    if (!errorEmpty)
    {
        $("#username, #email, #password, #confirmPassword").val("");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: What was a need for your code when all you want to do is refresh your page just do a `window.location.reload()` when your receive your response

Comment: I’m too new to web development to know that the answer may be simple enough to not require code.